# Не могу разобраться с классом DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing

Сама таблица:

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

ArrayList<Contact> contacts;


public TableModel(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;

}

public int returnSize(){
    return contacts.size();
}

public void addNewContact(ArrayList<Contact> contacts){
    contacts.add(new Contact());
    this.contacts=contacts;
}

public void removeContact(ArrayList<Contact> contacts, int row){
    contacts.remove(row);
    removeRow(row);
    this.contacts=contacts;

}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 3;
}

public int getRowCount(){
   return returnSize();
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    switch (column) {
        case 0:
            return "Имя";
        case 1:
            return "Фамилия";
        case 2:
            return "Мобильный телефон";
    }
    return "";
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
    Contact contact = contacts.get(row);
    switch (column){
        case 0: contact.setFirstName((String) aValue);
        break;
        case 1: contact.setSecondName((String) aValue);
        break;
        case 2: contact.setNumber((String) aValue);
        break;

    }

}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    Contact contact = contacts.get(row);
    switch (column) {
        case 0:
            return contact.getFirstName();
        case 1:
            return contact.getSecondName();
        case 2:
            return contact.getNumber();

    }
        return " ";
    }

    }
```

Класс с методом main и списком контактов:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ContactsBook extends JFrame {

ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
TableModel model;
JTable table;



public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ContactsBook().go();
}

ContactsBook(){
    contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

}



public void go(){
    System.out.println(contacts);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
    flowLayout.setHgap(30);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(flowLayout);
    JButton addBtn = new JButton("Добавить");
    addBtn.addActionListener(new addButtonListener());
    JButton dltBtn = new JButton("Удалить");
    dltBtn.addActionListener(new addDeleteListener());




    panel.add(addBtn);
    panel.add(dltBtn);







    model = new TableModel(contacts);
    System.out.println(model.returnSize());
    table = new JTable(model);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));

    add(BorderLayout.CENTER,scroll);
    add(BorderLayout.NORTH,panel);
    pack();


}



public class addButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int size=contacts.size();
        model.addNewContact(contacts);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{contacts.get(size).getFirstName(),contacts.get(size).getSecondName(),contacts.get(size).getNumber()});

    }
}

public class addDeleteListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        if (row>-1)
        model.removeContact(contacts,row);



    }
}

}
```

Класс Contact, поля которого мы добавляем в таблицу:

```
public class Contact {

private String firstName;
private String secondName;
private String number;



public Contact(){
    firstName="Введите имя";
    secondName="Введите фамилию";
    number="Введите мобильный номер";

}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getSecondName() {
    return secondName;
}

public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
    this.secondName = secondName;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

}

При создании таблицы я передаю в конструктор список Contacts, который эта таблица должна отобразить, но метод getRowCount() выкидывает ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Насколько я знаю эта ошибка выкидывается когда ссылка на `список = null`, но это не так я уже несколько раз выводил этот список в этом же объекте  и всё отображалось.

Вот ошибка полностью:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   TableModel.getRowCount(TableModel.java:39)    at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(DefaultTableModel.java:224)
>     at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.(DefaultTableModel.java:124)
>     at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.(DefaultTableModel.java:106)
>     at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.(DefaultTableModel.java:86)
>     at TableModel.(TableModel.java:9)     at
>   ContactsBook.go(ContactsBook.java:55)     at
>   ContactsBook.main(ContactsBook.java:20)

Comment: можете почтить стактрейс

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at TableModel.returnSize(TableModel.java:15)
 at TableModel.getRowCount(TableModel.java:36)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(DefaultTableModel.java:224)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:124)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:106)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:86)
 at TableModel.<init>(TableModel.java:9)
 at ContactsBook.go(ContactsBook.java:74)
 at ContactsBook.main(ContactsBook.java:20)

Comment: Добавьте стектрейс к вопросу, а в вопросе дополните код, чтоб можно было запустить тестово. Мне очень не нравится вот эти методы: public void addNewContact(ArrayList<Contact> contacts){
    contacts.add(new Contact());
    this.contacts=contacts;
}

public void removeContact(ArrayList<Contact> contacts, int row){
    contacts.remove(row);
    removeRow(row);
    this.contacts=contacts;

}, подозреваю что в них кроется проблема, на практике так ни кто не делает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы вызываете конструктор для `TableModel`, он в свою очередь, в конструкторе, неявно вызывает конструктор `DefaultTableModel`.

```
public TableModel(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
    super(); //DefaultTableModel()
    this.contacts = contacts;
}
```

Как видно, он вызывается до того, как вы присвоили `contacts`. В свою очередь в конструкторе `DefaultTableModel` вызывает метод `setDataVector`.

```
public void setDataVector(Vector<? extends Vector> dataVector,
                          Vector<?> columnIdentifiers) {
    this.dataVector = nonNullVector((Vector<Vector>)dataVector);
    this.columnIdentifiers = nonNullVector(columnIdentifiers);
    justifyRows(0, getRowCount());
    fireTableStructureChanged();
}
```

Как видно, в нём вызывается переопределённый вами метод `getRowCount()`, который и вызывает `contacts.size()`, до того момента, как `contacts` был присвоен.

Comment: Спасибо, что объяснили, а вы не могли подсказать как отобразить список по другому?

Comment: я не очень хорошо знаком со Swing. Мне кажется вам стоит в целом пересмотреть использование `DefaultTableModel`, так как вы переопределили много лишнего функционала + не факт, что измение списка контактов в `TableModel` отразится в `DefaultTableModel`

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel здесь вроде хорошие примеры использования